# Using rvest to extract links from (including blank rows)

Tags: r

I am trying to extract links from a table using rvest. The table also includes rows without link. Since I need to join the links to the original table the blank rows need to be included. html_attr("href") skips those lines, which makes it impossible to merge the links to the original table.

So for instance, this code gets the table with normal text/

```
library("rvest")

url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Simpsons_episodes"

simp <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]') %>%
  html_table() %>% 
  extract2(1)
```

This code extracts the links:

```
simp2 <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a')%>%
  html_attr("href")
```

And then i want to do something like

```
cbind(simp1,simp2)
```

But off that doesn't work since the table consists of 23 rows and there are only 13 links. Does anybody know how to get html_attr to include the blank rows so the vector simp2 has also 23 values (with 10 NA's or something like that)? Or with another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the nodeset (without the `a`!):

```
library(purrr)
simp2 <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]') %>%
  map_chr(~html_attr(html_node(., "a"), "href"))
```

which gives you a vector of length 23:

```
str(simp2)
# chr [1:23] "/wiki/Lance_Kramer" "/wiki/Mark_Kirkland" ...
```

Comment: great, thanks. Need to update my purrrrr knowledge:)